# How to get the Unicode of characters in java

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode, character-encoding, ide

I am using `eclipse` as `IDE` and when trying to print Arabic characters I got  `???????` , so I want to print the `Unicode` if the Arabic characters

```
String displayChar(char c) {
    if (c < '\u0010') {
        return "0x0" + Integer.toHexString(c);
    } else if (c < '\u0020' || c >= '\u007f') {
        return "0x" + Integer.toHexString(c);
    } else {
        return c+"";
    }
}
```

for example :

```
displayChar('م'); // output is ?
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: This the question : 
How to get the Unicode of Arabic characters in java

Comment: You need to use a font that supports those characters. Even if you use the correct unicode values, it still won't display correctly if the font doesn't support it. Please see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font) for more information.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  How are trying to print the characters?  Where to?  Where are the characters coming from?  Your Java code?  A file or stream that you are reading?  How are you reading it?

Comment: I still don't know what you're asking. If the code you've now given isn't doing what you want, what is the problem with it?

Comment: It might be that the character in the source code gets lost when the Java source file is saved? Otherwise I wouldn't know either.

Answer (score 2):

There are many way to get Unicode characters in Java.  For example, if you have a file that is properly encoded in UTF-8, then this will get the characters:

```
    try (Reader reader = new FileReader(file, "UTF-8")) {
        // read characters from the reader ...
    }
```

---

Your updated question seems to be saying that your real problem is with displaying characters, not "getting" them.  You have yet to properly explain **how** or **where** you are outputting the characters, but I will guess that the cause of you problem is one of the following:

- you don't have Arabic fonts installed (seems unlikely ...),
- the console (or whatever) that is displaying the characters doesn't understand Arabic characters (seems unlikely ...),
- the characters are corrupt; i.e. they are not what you expect them to be in the Java program, or
- you are using the wrong character encoding in the output stream.

The latter is the most likely explanation, but a proper diagnosis requires more information on the way that you are creating the output stream / writer and writing to it.  (Hint: the code you added to your question doesn't output anything.  It just turns a character into a Java String.)

Answer (score 0):

Characters in Java are just numeric values - so if `ch` is a char, you can just do `int i = ch;` and then print the value of `i`. (This ignores the complexities of code points vs characters - but I believe it is fine for the Arabic letters.)

Comment: It's a little more complicated for characters outside the basic multilingual plane, which are represented by surrogate pairs in Java.  Use `Character.isHighSurrogate()` and `Character.isLowSurrogate()` to check for those.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file encoding of you Java application as well as your version system supports Unicode. E.g. try to save your file as UTF-8. Otherwise it is likely that the encoding you see in your editor pane is lost. For maximum compatibility, you should encode your character using the `\u0645` code point in the source.

When you are displaying the character, make sure that your console supports Unicode, and that the font that it is using supports the character as well.

[EDIT]

Oh, and I've got a small update for your method as well:

```
public static String displayChar2(char c) {
    if (c < 0x20 || c >= 0x80) {
        return String.format("\\u%04X", (int) c);
    }
    return Character.toString(c);
}
```